# How can I convert datetime to date format in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I want to show a date in DD-MM-YYYY format in a datagrid. By default, SQLite stores the data in date-time format. So how can I convert date-time format to date format in flex by using SQLite?

Comment: For future readers, if you want the "usual" date format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) then you can also just use `DATE`:  `SELECT DATE(date_time)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `strftime`, from [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Example:

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', 'now')
```

output:

```
10-06-2010
```

Answer (score -7):

Look up Java until [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). It has methods to convert and is supported in SQLite. However it is mostly deprecated and replaced with Calender.