# sqlite convert 'dd.MM.yyyy' formated String to date

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a sqlite database on my android, whith a datetime column, that contains a date with the Format dd.MM.yyyy.
It's not my Database, I'm niot able to change the Dateformat.
I want to compare the date in the database with a String, which is representing a secon date, but everything I tryed failed.
How can I convert this column to a valid, compareable date?
date(), dattime() sdfttime() everything returns NULL.

Answer (score 10):

I searched on google for "sqlite3 date ddmmyyyy" and this post is the best solution (and the only one that worked for me amongst the posts listed on the bottom):

**Problem:**
A SQLite table contains dates in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` and need to be converted to SQLite native format `YYYY-MM-DD`

**Problem Example:**

```
sqlite> select id, calendar_day from tbl1;
id;calendar_day
4248281;2011-06-19
4248282;2011-06-19
4248283;19/06/2011
4248284;19/06/2011
```

**Solution Example:**

```
sqlite> update tbl1 set calendar_day = substr(calendar_day, 7) || "-" || substr(calendar_day,4,2)  || "-" || substr(calendar_day, 1,2) where id>4248282;
```

**Result Example:**

```
sqlite> select id, calendar_day from tbl1;
id;calendar_day
4248281;2011-06-19
4248282;2011-06-19
4248283;2011-06-19
4248284;2011-06-19
```

Thank you all!

Other posts inspected:

1. [Sqlite convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date/4429028#4429028)
2. [SOLite:Date formatter in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452038/solitedate-formatter-in-sqlite)
3. [How can I convert datetime to date format in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014667/how-can-i-convert-datetime-to-date-format-in-sqlite)
4. [Sqlite convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)
5. [How to convert a DD-MM-YYYY date format string into a YYYY-MM-DD date format string or into a NSDate object in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872657/how-to-convert-a-dd-mm-yyyy-date-format-string-into-a-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format-str)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query to change the column to the proper format for a text-date (assume table named `table` and column named `date`):

```
update table set date = substr(date, 7) || "-" || substr(date,4,2) 
  || "-" || substr(date, 1,2);
```

You can also turn this around into a where clause per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date/4429028#4429028).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want do this in the database (SQL) or in program code? In Java you may use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://d.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("21.03.1997");
```

Comment: I have to do  this in the sql code like: AND datetime(d.objectstop) <= '" + fb_str_date

Comment: didn't strftime need a input Value in yyyy-MM-dd format? if i try it, i receive null too