# Ormlite query using date

Tags: android, ormlite, query-builder

```
public GenericRawResults<Object[]> getCountByStatus(Date date,int status){
        Log.info("CallDayPlanningDao",date.toString());
        GenericRawResults<Object[]> rawResults=null;
        Dao callDayPlanningDao = getDao(CallDayPlanning.class);
        QueryBuilder query = callDayPlanningDao.queryBuilder();
        int year = date.getYear();
        int month = date.getMonth();
        Date date1 = new Date(year, month,1);
        Date date2 = new Date(year, month+1,1);

        Date startDate = new Date(date1.getTime()-5);
        Date endDate = new Date(date2.getTime()-5);
        try {
            **query.where().between("calldate", startDate, endDate);**//This line is not working
            if(status==Constant.cnStatus){
                query.where().in("callstatus", status,Constant.ccStatus);
            }else{
                query.where().eq("callstatus", status);
            }
            query.groupBy("calldate");
            query.selectRaw("calldate,count(*)");
            rawResults = callDayPlanningDao.queryRaw(query.prepareStatementString(), new DataType[] {
                            DataType.DATE_STRING, DataType.INTEGER });
            // page through the results

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rawResults;
    }
```

Well, I want to get the count of the object, but the condition of date is invalid, I get all the data from my database.Somebody could help me?Thanks.

Comment: This question is a candidate for being closed because it is hard to see what you are asking.  Please edit your post to explain what problems you are having.  Are you getting an exception?  You should also make your code sample more concise.  Is it not returning the right results?  `date1.getTime()-5` returns a time 5 milliseconds off of the other dates.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I want to get data of this month, so the date could be anyday of this month.`date1.getTime()-5` make sure all the data can be found. And, my question is, I want to get the data's count of everyday, but the query.where **query.where().between("calldate", startDate, endDate);** seems does't work.

Comment: The code looks fine to me.  I assume that all of the dates in the database are created with `new Date(year, month, 1);`.  If the dates are all over the place during the day then `groupBy()` is obviously not going to group them.  Can you should some input data and output results?

Answer (score 3):

I am new to ORMLite and faced the same problem when accessed SQLite database.

It took me a whole day today to figure it out, here is the summary:

1. I found format "yyyy-M-d H:m:s" works fine in ORMLite for dealing with SQLite DateTime data type, not ORMLite's default format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS".
2. For ORMLite to translate between "Java Date" and "SQLite DateTime", a persister class will be needed.
3. Here shows the code of the persister class I use, which override the public functions of DateStringType and use "dateFormatConfig" instead of defaultDateFormatConfig" :

`

```
public class DateStringSQLiteType extends DateStringType {

protected static final DateStringFormatConfig dateFormatConfig = new DateStringFormatConfig(
        "yyyy-M-d H:m:s");

private static final DateStringSQLiteType singleTon = new DateStringSQLiteType();

public static DateStringSQLiteType getSingleton() {
    return singleTon;
}

private DateStringSQLiteType() {
    super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[0]);
}

/**
 * Convert a default string object and return the appropriate argument to a
 * SQL insert or update statement.
 */
@Override
public Object parseDefaultString(FieldType fieldType, String defaultStr)
        throws SQLException {
    DateStringFormatConfig formatConfig = convertDateStringConfig(
            fieldType, dateFormatConfig);
    try {
        // we parse to make sure it works and then format it again
        return normalizeDateString(formatConfig, defaultStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw SqlExceptionUtil.create("Problems with field " + fieldType
                + " parsing default date-string '" + defaultStr
                + "' using '" + formatConfig + "'", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Return the SQL argument object extracted from the results associated with
 * column in position columnPos. For example, if the type is a date-long
 * then this will return a long value or null.
 * 
 * @throws SQLException
 *             If there is a problem accessing the results data.
 * @param fieldType
 *            Associated FieldType which may be null.
 */
@Override
public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results,
        int columnPos) throws SQLException {
    return results.getString(columnPos);
}

/**
 * Return the object converted from the SQL arg to java. This takes the
 * database representation and converts it into a Java object. For example,
 * if the type is a date-long then this will take a long which is stored in
 * the database and return a Date.
 * 
 * @param fieldType
 *            Associated FieldType which may be null.
 * @param sqlArg
 *            SQL argument converted with
 *            {@link #resultToSqlArg(FieldType, DatabaseResults, int)} which
 *            will not be null.
 */
@Override
public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos)
        throws SQLException {
    String value = (String) sqlArg;
    DateStringFormatConfig formatConfig = convertDateStringConfig(
            fieldType, dateFormatConfig);
    try {
        return parseDateString(formatConfig, value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw SqlExceptionUtil.create("Problems with column " + columnPos
                + " parsing date-string '" + value + "' using '"
                + formatConfig + "'", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Convert a Java object and return the appropriate argument to a SQL insert
 * or update statement.
 */
@Override
public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object obj) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = convertDateStringConfig(fieldType,
            dateFormatConfig).getDateFormat();
    return dateFormat.format((Date) obj);
}

/**
 * @throws SQLException
 *             If there are problems creating the config object. Needed for
 *             subclasses.
 */
@Override
public Object makeConfigObject(FieldType fieldType) {
    String format = fieldType.getFormat();
    if (format == null) {
        return dateFormatConfig;
    } else {
        return new DateStringFormatConfig(format);
    }
}

}
```

`

4. Define you data class with notation:

   `@DatabaseField(..., persisterClass = DateStringSQLiteType.class)
   private Date date;`
5. It worked fine for me, can do "Between" query like:

   ```
   list = foo.getDao().queryBuilder().where().between(HistoryStandardView.DATE_FIELD_NAME, new Date(98,1,1), new Date(115,1,1)).query();
   ```

ORMLite's logger shows the resulting statement:

[DEBUG] StatementExecutor query of 'SELECT * FROM `HistoryStandardView` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '1998-2-1 0:0:0' AND '2015-2-1 0:0:0' ' returned 2 results

Comment: I tried format "y-M-d H:m:s", it also does the job with SQLite.

Comment: I found the code below also does the job: `@DatabaseField(..., dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "y-M-d H:m:s")`

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work with ormlite 4.48. 
Have persisted an Entity with Date (1439226691506000L)

But the query by `getDao(Entity.class).queryBuilder().where().between("date", new Date(1438588896000L), new Date(1439226738376000L)).query();` doesn't return a single result. That sucks :(

Entity field looks like this: 
`@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = "date", persisterClass = DateStringSQLiteType.class)
    private Date date;`
Anybody discovers a mistake?

Comment: Have you tried the format attribute like `@DatabaseField(..., dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "y-M-d H:m:s")` ?

Comment: I'm now using `@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG, columnName = "date")` because that also works for me returning the entities when querying by `getDao().queryBuilder().where().between("date", start, end).query();`
where start and end are of type java.util.Date

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if am wrong is your `calldate` column's type is `DataType.DATE_STRING` ? If that's the case it means that the persisted data type is VARCHAR so when you execute your query your doing a String comparison and not a Date comparison. So to solve your problem you can either :

1. Change your `calldate` column's type to `DataType.DATE` which is represented as a `TIMESTAMP`.
2. Change your `calldate` column's type to `DataType.DATE_LONG`.
3. Find a way to do a String comparison that matches what your need (for instance calling the sql `date(calldate)` fonction if your `calldate` values matches a Time Strings format see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Here is what i did, it's not pretty but works like wanted to:

```
QueryBuilder<OffreEntity, Integer> qb = this.daoOffre.queryBuilder();
//Need to format the date i want to compare so it can actually be compare with what i have on db
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
String correctFormat = dateFormatter.format(dateLimite);
//In db the date is represented as a VARCHAR with format dd/MM/yy so i need to reformat so it matches yyMMdd
String rawQuery = String.format("substr(%1$s,7)||substr(%1$s,4,2)||substr(%1$s,1,2) > '%2$s'", OffreEntity.COLUMN_NAME_DATE, correctFormat);
qb.where().raw(rawQuery);
offresDept = qb.query();
```

Hope it helps!

> Ps: Thanks to Jack Douglas for the [date format query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429028/665823)

Comment: @Karl "%1$s" means the first String passed as parameter to `String.format()` in this case it would be `OffreEntity.COLUMN_NAME_DATE`.