# How to select data between two dates from sqlite db in dd-mm-yyyy format?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have date column in my database in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

i want to search the data between two dates.

i tried

```
SELECT * FROM t_data where orderdate between '01-05-2012 00:00:00' and '31-05-2012 23:59:59'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM t_data where orderdate >= '05-05-2012' and  orderdate <='31-05-2012'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sqlite convert string to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)

Comment: The answers to the question mvp linked will do what you want. You'd be much better off using a standard date format like ISO-8601 though. Then SQLite queries will work in the way you expect: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 13):

use :

```
select * from tbl_name where Attribute_name between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd';
```

here Attribute_name is `date_time` column name

example :

```
select * from tbl_node where mydate between '2014-02-02' and '2014-02-06';

1|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:00:44
2|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:01:03
3|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:00:57
```

Answer (score 2):

The date format must be YYYY-MM-DD in SQLite.