# How to search between two dates in java with Sqlite database

Tags: java, jcalendar

I am using jCalender to input date

```
String from_date = ((JTextField) txt_bilty_date_start.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
String to_date = ((JTextField) txt_bilty_date_end.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
String sql = " "; //what query I need to use
```

[image]

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957274/how-to-select-data-between-two-dates-from-sqlite-db-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: I think my answer answers this question please rate and confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not java pro but SQL statement could be like this

```
select * from POSTS where Id = 1
       and Date between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27'
```

or can use

```
select * from POSTS where Id = 1
       and Date >= '2011/02/25' and Date <= '2011/02/27'
```

Comment: i am using jCalender component to pick up date in java.. and format specified only "MMM d, yyyy"

How can search with String date in SqLite DB Query in java..
plz help me its vry urgent and  important for me..