# Query "Select max(date) from table where date <= somedate" not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am querying a SQLite database table as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) from Intra360 WHERE Date <= "05/04/2013 00:00"
```

The right record in return should be the number 47, i.e. `04/04/2013 23:00`:

[image: raw data]

However, the execution of this statement returns a different value:

[image: SQL output]

I confess I know almost nothing about SQL, but this outcome is strange. Where am I being wrong?

**NOTE** "Intra360" is the name of the table and the field containing the dates is called "Date"

**ADDITIONAL NOTE** what I need is the closest available date to a user input. It is a Python program which is making some analysis but when the user inputs the dates is not necessarily true they will exist in the database. So I'm just trying to re-select them in a way that the proper SQL statement that will load the data to be used in the analysis won't fail execution because of the missing record. So "05/04/2013 00:00" is the user input, and the query should be done hence starting from 04/04/2013 (and not definetely 04/06/2013).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparisons are performed on strings with alphabetical ordering, not on datetime stamps with chronological ordering.

Store your datetimes in a format that compares the way you want. For example, unix epoch timestamps and ISO 8601 `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` datetimes have this property.

If you cannot influence how the data is stored, you can use `substr()` to mangle the timestamps in SQL. See e.g. [Sqlite convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date) for more.

Comment: I was fearing something like this. The problem is that I cannot touch the database, the values will be always stored like that. Is there a way to move around the problem from the SQL statement and not from the data structure? (sorry once again, I understand nothing of SQL so most probably my question is very stupid).

Comment: Ok, I realized the problem. All my dates are stored as strings cause they come from external data providers that for some reason don't allow changes to this structure. I guess I will have to make a work around in Python and querying the strings. Thanks for explanation, if you know a way to do what I asked (even if I think is impossible, isn't it?) I would be glad

Comment: Sorry, I've read your edit later. That was the solution, thanks a lot!