# How to filter SQL by time (greater and less than)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like, spatialite

I want to query a subset from a dataset. Each row has a time stamp of the following format:

```
2014-04-25T17:25:14
2014-04-25T18:40:16
2014-04-25T18:44:57
2014-04-25T19:10:32
2014-04-25T20:22:12
...
```

Currently, I use the following query to select a time-based subset:

```
time LIKE '%2014-04-25T18%' OR time LIKE '%2014-04-25T19%'
```

This becomes quite complicated when you start to filter by mintutes or seconds.

Is there a way to run a query that such as ...

```
time > '%2014-04-25T18%' AND time < '%2014-04-25T19%'
```

A regular expression would be okay, too.

The database is a [SpatiaLite database](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/home). The time column is of type VARCHAR.

Comment: What is the data type of that time column? And what DB engine do you use?

Comment: @mhasan . . . That is one way to express time zones.  The numbers are offsets from GMT.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No. I just cut off the time string to filter by hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your posts and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608394/356895) I came up with this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE DATETIME(
  substr(time,1,4)||'-'||
  substr(time,6,2)||'-'||
  substr(time,9,2)||' '||
  substr(time,12,8)
) 
BETWEEN DATETIME('2014-04-25 18:00:00') AND DATETIME('2014-04-25 19:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is being treated as a string and based on the example above:

```
time LIKE '%2014-04-25T18%' AND time <> '%2014-04-25T18:00:00:000'
```

Otherwise, you could convert the date to seconds since midnight and add 60 minutes to that to create the range part of the filter

```
DECLARE @test DATETIME = '2014-04-25T17:25:14'
SELECT @test
, CONVERT(DATE,@test) AS JustDate
, DATEDIFF(s,CONVERT(DATETIME,(CONVERT(DATE,@test))), @test) AS SecondsSinceMidnight

-- 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours = 86400
```