# SQLite Convert String to Date when date column has single digit months and days

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, date

I am trying to mimic the solution in this answer post: [Sqlite convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)

The problem I am running into though is that my raw text date field contains dates in the following format:

```
1/5/2014 0:00:00
```

instead of:

```
01/05/2014 0:00:00
```

How can I account for this single digit month/day variability and adapt the code for my purpose?  I cannot think of a decent way.  I have thought of using excel to create a conversion table that I could join upon.  Is there a more elegant approach?

**Edit on 10/2/2014:**

I would have thought there would be more like 81 possible combinations to identify.  Or Maybe there is a simpler way I am not thinking of?

```
1/1/
1/2/
1/3/
1/4/
1/5/
1/6/
1/7/
1/8/
1/9/

2/1/
2/2/
2/3/
2/4/
2/5/
2/6/
2/7/
2/8/
2/9/

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are eight different combinations of one- or two-digit fields; you just have to check for all of them:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN Trans_Date LIKE '_/_/____ _:__:__'  THEN substr(Trans_Date, 10, 1)
       WHEN Trans_Date LIKE '_/_/____ __:__:__' THEN substr(Trans_Date, 10, 2)
       ...
       END AS Hour,
       ...
FROM LS2014
```

Comment: I would have expected there to be more like 81 possible combinations, right?  Or maybe I thinking of it incorrectly?

    1/1/
1/2/
1/3/
1/4/
1/5/
1/6/
1/7/
1/8/
1/9/

2/1/
2/2/
2/3/
2/4/
2/5/
2/6/
2/7/
2/8/
2/9/
...

Comment: The actual values do not matter; for `substr()` to work correctly, you just need to know the number of characters to skip.

Comment: Oh, that is a very good point!  And actually, I may not be understanding your above code completely.  What do the underscores do?  They represent any value basically?

Comment: For some reason, I feel like SQLite documentation is hard to read.  Anyway, I found this [T-SQL related link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28SQL.80%29.aspx) and I get it now!!  I didn't even know you could use an _ like that in SQL!  Your solution makes total sense now! :)