# Android SQLite database delete

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to delete the all rows by dates. In the table I have the rows with this format:`2014-01-01`. Now, I want to delete the all rows by date range.
I have created this method, but I believe there is a syntax error:

```
 public void deleteAllEntrate_e_uscite(View v) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      db.delete(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, MyTable.DATA + "BETWEEN" +dateAndTime+ "AND" +dateAndTime1, null);
    db.close();
    finish(); 

}
```

Comment: Convert String to date. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4428795

Comment: Asked bazillion times...  First spaces...  Second apostrophes...  But of course you should use parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your keywords:

```
MyTable.DATA + "BETWEEN" +dateAndTime+ "AND" +dateAndTime1
```

you need spaces AND you need apostrophes, since your dates are strings:

```
MyTable.DATA + " BETWEEN '" +dateAndTime+ "' AND '" +dateAndTime1 +"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

When concatenating you are not leaving a space between the elements.

```
db.delete(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, MyTable.DATA + " BETWEEN " +dateAndTime+ " AND " +dateAndTime1, null);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly as I said. Don't forget to add the apostrophes around the dates, since they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing date(not column of type int),you have to use apostrophes.So the query will be like this.

**db.delete(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, MyTable.DATA + "BETWEEN '" +dateAndTime+ "' AND '" +dateAndTime1+"'", null);**

Also add one white space between 'BETWEEN' & the DATE PARAMETER.Other wise you will get SQLiteException.
One suggestion too,before executing every query please ensure that the db connection(here 'db') is not null.