# Sqlite3 conversion MM/DD/YY string to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, concatenation

I am trying to convert a string column of existing values from 'MM/DD/YY' to  'YYYY/MM/DD'.

Example Data:

Table: backlog_backlogData

[LoadDate]
06/29/18
06/29/18
06/28/18
07/24/18
07/24/18

I have tried this (in SQLite Manager FireFox extention):

```
UPDATE backlog_backlogData SET LoadDate = substr(LoadDate, 7, 2)||”-“||substr(LoadDate, 1,2)||”-“||substr(LoadDate, 4,2)
```

Unfortunately, the column is updated with only the first substr (results: 18).  It seems like SQLite does not like concatenates ||?

I've searched for an answer and have not found anything that works.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confident it was an issue with the SQLite Manager Firefox Extension. I ran the following code from cursor in python and it worked:

```
UPDATE backlog_backlogData SET LoadDate = substr(LoadDate, 7, 2) || '-' || substr(LoadDate, 1,2) || '-' || substr(LoadDate, 4,2)
```

I then reset my data and reran the code within the SQLite Manager Extension and it only processed the code up to the first concat.

EDIT: Thanks for the help below!

Answer (score 0):

#### try replacing ” with "

you can check the query with a SELECT statement

```
  SELECT substr(LoadDate, 7, 2)||"-"||
         substr(LoadDate, 1,2)||"-"||
         substr(LoadDate, 4,2) 
     from  backlog_backlogData
```

[example using python to convert date table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35544470/8882607)

Comment: With SELECT, I get no such row LoadDate.  I appreciate the python method to convert though.  I'll look into that more.