# How to compare the 2 datetime values if they are in str/text format?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Blame it on my bad design.
I have the column datatype of datetime as text.
And now, I need to compare (<) 2 datetime values if one is greater than the other.
Getting the exception as "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

The values are in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Am using sqlite3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite-convert-string-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date).

Comment: I am actually trying delete few rows if datetime is less than  6 weeks for instance.

Comment: You should be able to truncate your strings to only use "YYYY-MM-DD" - then a stringcompare of  `"2018-06-08" < "2018-06-04"`  should work. You would need to "calculate" your targett date as string as well...

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `pandas.to_datetime` to get the `Timestamp` object from the string for which a comparison is much easier. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = pd.to_datetime("1991-01-20 05:00:00")
date2 = pd.to_datetime("2005-10-01 15:12:00")
print(date1 < date2) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.mktime(parse(ts).timetuple())`  where 'ts' is your timestamp string.

Ex:

```
>>> ts1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%M-%d %I:%M:%S")
>>> ts2 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%M-%d %I:%M:%S")
>>>
>>> ts1
'2018-02-21 03:02:58'
>>> ts2
'2018-03-21 03:03:11'
>>>
>>> time.mktime(parse(ts1).timetuple())
1519162378.0
>>>
>>> time.mktime(parse(ts2).timetuple())
1521581591.0
```