# How we can convert sub-string of a clob field to datetime in SQLITE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, datetime, select

Example data fields are like :

```
DATE+05/06/2022 23:59:59;
DATE+06/05/2022 23:59:59;
DATE+14/05/2022 23:59:59;
DATE+26/05/2022 23:59:59;
```

SUBSTR data we have in dates as :

```
05/06/2022 23:59:59
06/05/2022 23:59:59
14/05/2022 23:59:59
26/05/2022 23:59:59
```

Required date fields are like :

```
2022-06-05 23:59:59
2022-05-06 23:59:59
2022-05-14 23:59:59
2022-05-26 23:59:59
```

Things I've tried which are populating NULL as end result:

- CASTING to datetime [ `CAST('05/06/2022 23:59:59' as datetime)`]
- Use of datetime() [`datetime('05/06/2022 23:59:59')`]
- Using strftime() [`strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','05/06/2022 23:59:59')`]

Links I've found which are not being relevant :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429028/2517880
- https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-strftime-function

> I'm looking for any other way than splitting and concatenating date field.

Comment: SQLite is not that flexible with dates. You will have to recreate the dates with sunstring() and concatenation.

Comment: @forpas Is it possible to convert string DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS by any function(s)?

Comment: `substr()` and the concatenation operator `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have built-in functions to convert strings to dates. You would need to use string functions to recompose the dates.

For a format lke: `'DATE+05/06/2022 23:59:59;'`, you can do:

```
substr(mycol, 12, 4) 
|| '-' || substr(mycol, 9,  2)
|| '-' || substr(mycol, 6,  2)
|| ' ' || substr(mycol, 17, 8)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e2425deea49bba745d9537e7eb62f170)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'DATE+05/06/2022 23:59:59;' mycol
    union all select 'DATE+06/05/2022 23:59:59;'
    union all select 'DATE+14/05/2022 23:59:59;'
    union all select 'DATE+26/05/2022 23:59:59;'
)
select substr(mycol, 12, 4) 
        || '-' || substr(mycol, 9,  2)
        || '-' || substr(mycol, 6,  2)
        || ' ' || substr(mycol, 17, 8) mydate
from mytable
```

```
| mydate              |
| :------------------ |
| 2022-06-05 23:59:59 |
| 2022-05-06 23:59:59 |
| 2022-05-14 23:59:59 |
| 2022-05-26 23:59:59 |
```