# sqlite3 fails to import data from only 1 tsv file

Tags: bash, sqlite

### Issue

I'm creating a script that blends a load of tsv files with the aim of then importing the data into my sqlite3 table. However, I have noticed that one of my files doesn't seem to get imported with my script like all the others. It also doesn't appear to import when I run it manually.

As the data is able to get into the temp table without issue, I thought the issue may lie with the date column, but even with amending it in the data to be in Y-M-D format, for some reason it still doesn't import.

Can someone confirm what seems to be wrong with the sample data as all other tsv files appear to import without issue?

sample.tsv

```
company1    account1    platform1   05/05/2020  28823   client1 191361
company2    account2    platform2   05/05/2020  47188   cleint2 16597
company3    account3    platform3   05/06/2020  28823   client1 191903
company4    account4    platform4   05/06/2020  47188   cleint2 15407
company5    account5    platform5   05/07/2020  28823   client1 196450
company6    account6    platform6   05/07/2020  47188   cleint2 14678
company7    account7    platform7   05/08/2020  28823   client1 191809
company8    account8    platform8   05/08/2020  47188   cleint2 14489
company9    account9    platform9   05/09/2020  28823   client1 195405
```

### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

cd final/client/

for f in $(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.tsv" -printf "%f\n"); do

sqlite3 -batch ~/SQL/.databases/database.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS companydata_client(
Company  TEXT NOT NULL,
Account TEXT NOT NULL,
Platform        TEXT NOT NULL,
Impression_Date_Delivered  DATE NOT NULL,
Client_ID   TEXT NOT NULL,
Client      TEXT NOT NULL,
Impressions     INTEGER,
UNIQUE(Company,Account,Platform,Impression_Date_Delivered,Client_ID, Client,Impressions)
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wand(
Company  TEXT NOT NULL,
Account TEXT NOT NULL,
Platform        TEXT NOT NULL,
Impression_Date_Delivered  DATE NOT NULL,
Client_ID   TEXT NOT NULL,
Client      TEXT NOT NULL,
Impressions     INTEGER
);

.mode tabs
.separator \t
.import $f wand

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO companydata_client (Company,Account,Platform,Impression_Date_Delivered,Client_ID,Client,Impressions)

SELECT
        CAST (Company AS TEXT),
        CAST (Account AS TEXT),
        CAST (Platform AS TEXT),
        strftime('%d-%m-%Y',Impression_Date_Delivered),
        CAST (Client_ID AS Text),
        CAST (Client AS TEXT),
        CAST (Impressions AS Integer)
FROM wand;
EOF

done

cd ../../
```

Comment: Your date separators area forward slashes in your tsv file, so I guess using dashes in your code will not work.

Comment: @00 I thought the same but even when converting `/` to `-` and changing the date order it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @00 yes sorry that was a mistake in the post. Can confirm this has now been amended

Comment: I've put in a vote to close as a duplicate, even though I've answered this question separately. Sometimes, that is just clearer, but linking it to a duplicate connects the questions (and answers), which may be useful for others (since the suggested duplicate question has a variety of answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite appears to be somewhat unfortunate in this case, as the `strftime` is to convert dates to strings, but there seems to be no equivalent `strptime`, that would convert strings to dates. (In fact, all dates are effectively strings in Sqlite. I think they are only parsed and interpreted as dates for the relevant functionality.)

Going by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date), you would end up with something like this instead:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO companydata_client (Company,Account,Platform,Impression_Date_Delivered,Client\
_ID,Client,Impressions)
SELECT
        CAST (Company AS TEXT),
        CAST (Account AS TEXT),
        CAST (Platform AS TEXT),
        substr(Impression_Date_Delivered, 7) || '-' ||
            substr(Impression_Date_Delivered, 4, 2) || '-' ||
            substr(Impression_Date_Delivered, 1, 2),
        CAST (Client_ID AS Text),
        CAST (Client AS TEXT),
        CAST (Impressions AS Integer)
FROM wand;
EOF
```

Not the most readable line, but that seems to be the way to go (until someone else comes up with a better answer). The formatting should yield a string that Sqlite can interpret as a date.

Aside: I changed the type of `wand.Impression_Date_Delivered` to `TEXT`, since that is what it is at that point: it is only inserted as a "date" in `companydata_client`.