# How do you select the most recent date from a database table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a SQLite query that will check a column of dates in a table and select only the most recent one. The date format in table is dd/mm/yyyy

```
SELECT MAX(created) FROM account
```

That only seems to bring up the date with the highest day number.

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD and your code will work.

Comment: If you don't want to or can't convert the date field for some reason, you can cast a query as a date. Almost exact same question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)

Comment: I'll have a go tomorrow with a clear head thanks

Comment: @forpas hey sorry for delayed reply, that worked great thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [forpas for the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023118/how-do-you-select-the-most-recent-date-from-a-database-table-in-sqlite#comment118471151_67023118). This code worked with the suggested edit of changing the dates format in the table to yyyy-MM-dd:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM account AS a WHERE created = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM account AS b WHERE custid = @custid)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("custid", Global.selectedCust);
                SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    newestDate = read["created"].ToString();
                }
```