# Change Format from DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm

Tags: sqlite, datetime, substr

I tried to use the below statement to change DateTimes into  SQLite desired DateTime format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` so as to perform calculations. But the statement gives me an "incomplete input" message. Sample input-output is below:

> e.g. 03/05/2020 17:34 => 2020-05-03 17:34

```
> UPDATE Combined_Bike_Ride SET started_at = substr(started_at,7,4) ||"-"|| substr(started_at(4,2)||"-"||substr(started_at(1,2)||" "||substr(started_at(12,2)||":"||substr(started_at(15,2)
```

What do you think is missing in the statement?

Comment: Change the `(` inside substr to `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for debugging in such cases, take "baby steps".  Change content in a dummy column in a dummy test database. Then split your update command to smaller parts, adding one at a time.

It took about 2 minutes to see that you put a bracket where a comma was needed.

```
UPDATE dt 
    SET 
       md = 
       substr(sa,7,4) ||"-"|| 
       substr(sa,4,2)||"-"||
       substr(sa,1,2)||" "|| 
       substr(sa,12,2)||":"||
       substr(sa,15,2)
```

You had  `substr(sa(4,2)`  in  most of them, making it an (incomplete) function.

Btw, it's perfectly OK to split the SQL statement over lines, which makes it more readable.

Most important lesson: in debugging  **take baby steps**

Notice btw that your function will fail if one of the dates do not have leading zero. It is more reliable to do this in a programming language, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)