# How do I convert a TEXT type into datetime in DB Browser for SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, casting

For some reason this database enters the date and time information under the name column. This is a problem because the schema shows that name is a TEXT type. So the entry is something like:

```
1 Jul 2023 10:22:48 (as TEXT)
```

It seems this format cannot be casted into a datetime format using cast as I have tried:

```
SELECT
  CAST(tracks.name as datetime) as datetime
FROM tracks
```

but this only returns a single number which is the first 1

Is there any way I could change this to the right date and time format?

I just need to see the time difference between the entries.

Comment: SQLite [doesn't have a date type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429028/256196).

Comment: See https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values for the string formats that SQLite date and time functions understand. Use one of them or one of the numeric formats when storing dates/times in a database and your life will be much simpler.