# How to convert a DD-MM-YYYY date format string into a YYYY-MM-DD date format string or into a NSDate object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsdate, date-format

I have read date from XML which give me back string where the date is like `DD-MM-YYYY`. But when I want to add it to my core data database, SQLite sorts me that wrong so I have to convert it to date format or to string like: `YYYY-MM-DD`. But SQLite does not support either `Date()` or `To_Date()` functions. Can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to format a date in Objective C.

Here's a quick example which might not do exactly what you want, but should hopefully give some pointers:

```
// Convert my dd-mm-yyyyy string into a date object
NSString *stringDate = @"01-02-2011";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

// Convert my date object into yyyy-mm-dd string object
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *formattedStringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

[dateFormatter release];
```

Hope this helps!

Nick.

Comment: Will it work for my example? when i have to use dateFromString and the string is DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: Good question! I've posted an update to my post. I've not tested this code, but hopefully it gives the idea! Best of luck. N

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
  NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
  NSString *elmentendo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate];

Comment: Are you sure your DD-MM-YYYY date is in the `string` variable?

Comment: I gues it does not support DD-MM-YYYY format because it throw s back nil if I run it after                                             NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

Comment: Yes - this is great! I just checked and it seems to work fine on my machine. What output do you get on your machine when you print out elmentendo to the terminal?

Comment: Yes Douwe I get string right from function                              - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {                     So I work with string

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094819/nsdateformatter-returning-nil-in-os-4-0

Comment: Nick Your answer was right and worked perfectly for date  like @"23-01-1989" but I have date in format @"23.01.1989" i just have to solve how to convert that maybe i write for that a function once more thank

Answer (score 1):

Using Nick's tutorial and answer the solution is :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01.02.1989"];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        // Convert my date object into yyyy-mm-dd string object
        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString *formattedStringDate = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date];

        [dateFormatter release];
        [dateFormatter1 release];
        NSLog(formattedStringDate);

        objektObrat.dateOfObrat = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:formattedStringDate];
```

Comment: Great you found a solution to the problem & pleased to have helped! Good luck with the rest of your app. N