# How to retrive all the data from sqlite according to the date

Tags: android, sqlite

I am Facing a problem in a query.In which i retrive the data from database according to the date like if todays date is 17/09/2016 i want all the data which is saved on this date the problem is when i retrive its show me only one data and there are many data present in my database i cant get out from this problem.
i know that it is a silly question but i am stuck in that from 2 to 3 days.

```
 sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from mytable where Date = (select max(Date) from mytable WHERE Date < DATE('now') );", null);

   Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from BluetoothDevice WHERE Date = date('now');", null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Date date = new Date();
        date.setTime(Long.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"))));
        result.add(
                new BluetoothDevice(
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Device")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address")),
                        date

                )
        );
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show the code that reads the rows.

Comment: editd my question

Comment: Save a date always as long!

Answer (score 0):

That query would never retrieve TODAY's data. `date('now')` will always be now, so `Sep 16, 2016`. You then query for anything BEFORE  (`<`) that day, so you only get records `Sep 15, 2016` and earlier. You then take the MAX of those earlier dates, which can never be HIGHER than `Sep 15` (because that's what your `where` specifies) and use an equality test on that.

So effectively, for a query on Sep 16th, you're running `where date = 'Sep 15'`

Why can you just have

```
SELECT ... WHERE date = date('now')
```

?

Comment: how are you storing your dates? as actual date/datetime fields, or as strings? if they're strings, you HAVE to ensure that they're in the same format that `date('now')` erturns. `'sep 16, 2016' == '2016-09-16'` are FALSE by string comparison standards, but by human standards represent the same day.

Comment: i have datetime

Comment: then you have to account for the time component as well. `'2016-09-16 12:52:00' = '2016-09-16'` is FALSE, because the date-only value is assumed to have an invisible `00:00:00` time component.

Comment: can u give me the exact query bcuz i am new to android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014667/how-can-i-convert-datetime-to-date-format-in-sqlite

Comment: but this will return only date ?'

Comment: Following your current format, you could have the query like so:
"SELECT * from mytable where Date LIKE %('now')%". Of course, if the date formatting is different (e.g. yy/mm/dd vs mm/dd/yy) this still won't have results

Comment: I have yyyy/MMMM/dd